# Listen for mouse clicked on a textfield in JavaFX FXML

Tags: javafx, textfield, fxml, scenebuilder

(Solved)I am using scene builder and FXML, and I am trying to make it so that if the user clicks on a text field, it enables that text field for editing and disables another text field. I can't seem to figure out how to make an action event that listen for the click of a mouse in a text field, and all the questions I've seen posted are for FX, not FXML.

This is the code I have so far:

```
@FXML
    public void radiohandleBW(MouseEvent event){
        if(event.getSource() == fullBW){ //I think this line is throwing the error
            if(fullBW.isPressed()){
                System.out.println("pressed");
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's the compiler error with it:

```
Executing D:\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Statgain0.0.1\dist\run867462295\Statgain0.0.1.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#radiohandleBW', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
file:/D:/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/Statgain0.0.1/dist/run867462295/Statgain0.0.1.jar!/statgain0/pkg0/pkg1/FXMLStatgain0.0.1.fxml:45

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at statgain0.pkg0.pkg1.Statgain001.start(Statgain001.java:25)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application statgain0.pkg0.pkg1.Statgain001
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory D:\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Statgain0.0.1\dist\run867462295
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

If I am doing something wrong please tell me, I know it is more than just a simple fix.

Comment: The error is occurring when you load the FXML file, and is to do with the association between the FXML element and the Java method. You haven't posted enough code to diagnose the problem: trim your FXML file down to the minimum and trim your controller down to the minimum so that they still generate the same error, and then post the entire FXML and controller in the question.

Comment: Actually I just fixed the problem. All I had to do was take out the words MouseEvent event, because in scene builder I had already declared it as a clickable event. I found it on a link somewhere but can't find it again. Thanks though!

Comment: `onAction` takes an `ActionEvent` as parameter, not a `MouseEvent`. Since `FXMLBuilder` is looking for the method signatures `void methodName(ActionEvent)` or `void methodName()` the exception is thrown...